# how do you stop downloads from AWS S3 with the object url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a website similar to video hosting where i need to display upload videos and images and have the images be visible and also the videos if they are purchased, however their locations are saved in the database (MongoDB) and are displayed on the web-page and therefore show up in the network tab in the developer console.

this means that if you click on the link e.g. "https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key-name/folder/file-name.mp4" it will auto download, this only happens on chrome though but not Firefox where it just displays the object with no download option.  i have tried to change the bucket policy, add encryption but either that causes the images that i want to display to become invisible as they are not publicly accessible or just has no effect and still allows for the video to be downloaded. is there any way for me to have the images and videos in the same bucket and have them both be visible under the right circumstances but block access to the bucket and prevent them from being downloaded by anyone but the bucket owner?

Comment: The object being visible on the website in the browser is the **exact same thing** as the user downloading the object, to be able to view it the browser downloads the data. You cannot prevent that without breaking the website.

Comment: Does s3/cloudfront signed URLs (or cookies) fit your needs? You generate them dynamically and insert those links into your authenticated users session so only they will have a temporarily valid link. They can be time limited, ip restricted etc and accessing the url directly (without the signed cookie/url) would fail. Once you give out that URL (to a logged in user etc) as @luk2302 points out its easily downloaded though :-/

Comment: But note that there is absolutely no way to ultimately prevent a user from downloading the data, you can only make it slightly more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop the downloads because the ability to show videos and images in a browser also means that the files are accessible via URL (that's how the browser fetches them).

One option is to use an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. The way it would work is:

- Users authenticate to your back-end service
- When a user requests access to one of the videos or images, your back-end checks that they are authorized to access the file
- If so, your back-end **generates an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL** and includes it in the web page (eg `<img src='...'>`)
- When the user's browser accesses that URL, Amazon S3 will verify that the URL is correct and the time-limit has not expired. If it's OK, then the file is provided.
- Once the time limit expires, the URL will not work

This will not prevent a file being downloaded, but it will limit the time during which it can be done.

Alternate methods would involve serving content via **streaming** instead of via a file, but that is a much more complex topic. (For example, think about how Netflix streams content to users rather than waiting for them to download files.)

Comment: And every movie that is available via streaming is freely downloadable a few minutes later because it is just a little bit more complicated to retrieve the full file.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will look more into pre-signed URLs. hopefully that method will be sufficient until the project gains traction and i can afford to get professionals to help work on it. thanks.